# Joomla: how to set an offset for the featured articles in my homepage?

Tags: joomla, offset

I set the Home menu item to show all the featured articles of all categories in my homepage, and everything is working fine.

Now I want to set an offset for those articles to show them starting from the fifth article and not the first, is that possible with no hack on the core?

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to change core files you could make a small trick. You could set # Leading Articles with your offset number, hide them with css display: none; and work with # Intro Articles. A better clean solution is to use a module with an option for offset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer emmanuel! Yeah! Well I thought about that but, as I have a module displaying the first four articles in the same page, I would get those articles duplicated to the Google spider, which I guess is not a good practice.

Comment: That's true, it would be better to find a module with native offset support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather do like this... Setting 4 Leading articles (as also suggested) then use jQuery to .remove() those Leading articles! Thank you.

Comment: You wouldn't need to set the articles as leading. You could just use the indexes of the article wrappers to remove them.

Comment: Thank you for you answer isherwood! I don't really get what you mean though... What indexes are you talking about? Maybe by setting single articles IDs to exclude?

Comment: `$('article:eq(0), article:eq(1), ... ').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

I apply a custom CSS class to the module, then do something like this:

```
.home-latest-news ul > li:nth-child(1), 
.home-latest-news ul > li:nth-child(2), 
.home-latest-news ul > li:nth-child(3), 
.home-latest-news ul > li:nth-child(4), 
.home-latest-news ul > li:nth-child(5) {
    display: none;
}
```

It doesn't offer the non-programmer usability or SEO features that a module would, but it's very simple.